# Make two divs scroll across screen next to each other

Tags: html, animation, scroll

I'd like to align two divs next to each other, and have them scroll across the screen from right to left. I know how to do this for a single piece of text enclosed in paragraph tags, but would like to do this for the two divs. Is that possible? Thanks.

Comment: Please provide some example code of you attempting to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Check this example code -

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
      <title>HTML marquee Tag</title>
   </head>
   <body>
    <marquee>
        <div>
          <div style = "float:left">
              DIV 1 DATA 
          </div>
          <div style = "float:left">
              DIV 2 DATA
          </div>
        </div>
    </marquee>
   </body>
</html>
```